# With python plotly, how can I change the font and style of the hover labels?

Tags: python, plotly

From https://plot.ly/python/line-and-scatter/#line-and-scatter-plots

[image: line and scatter plot]

I would like to create a plot just like this, but I'd like to style the labels to the right differently (from the image where `image`, `lines+markers` and `lines` are).

I've added `textfont=dict(color='black'),` to the go.Scatter line does nothing.  I've added a `Layout` object with `font=dict(color='black'),`, does nothing.  And I've added similar to `XAxis` and `YAxis` without anything changing there, either.

---

For my use I'll be plotting really light colours (yellows, and green), which are fine for the dot, but really bad for the text.  I'll also have longer text for the label, but plot.ly just converts it to ellipses, and I haven't been able to figure a way to prevent that, and just show all the text.

Comment: Plotly does not have this feature, see: https://community.plot.ly/t/trace-hover-label-color/12584